# Select the result instead of for loop in PHP using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

There are two table :

```
user_playlist
---------------
id
user_id
playlist_id
title
description

playlist
-------------
id
user_playlist_id
video_id
```

And I would like to get the data:

All the user_playlist of a specific user, and for each playlist , check whether the video_id exist

Right now I use php to get user_playlist first and foreach user_playlist count whether the video_id is exist in playlist.

It works but seems not efficient, hope can done by a SQL Query.

Thanks for helping.

**Update:**

```
**Sample data**

user_playlist
1, 1, 1, list_1_title, list_1_description
2, 1, 3, list_5_title, list_5_description

playlist
1, 1 , 5
2, 1 , 4
3, 2 , 6
```

for example , a user id #1 and video #4 result is (using up as alias of user_playlist) :

```
up.id up.title        up.description      up.user_id     is_video_id_select
1     list_1_title    list_1_description      1              1
3     list_5_title    list_5_description      1              0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done using simple [`left join`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)

```
SELECT up.*,pl.id, pl.user_playlist_id,
(
CASE WHEN pl.video_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_video_id_select
)
FROM user_playlist as up 
INNER JOIN playlist 
ON up.playlist_id = pl.id
WHERE up.user_id = 'x' // where x is a user id
```

this will bring the common data between both the table

for more see the reference link i gave you

i hope this was helpful

Comment: Thanks. seems the video_id is not considered?